# How to use fields in Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I have seen in documentation that fields are not rendered in the view, and instead it can be used in helpers, partials etc. but I can't find a way how they are used.
The documentation says to use it like this:

```
{{ cms:field:some_label }}
```

But I am courios how can I use that? I wanted to be able to define some text in the snippet and then, use that field in my partial or in my helper function to form some data that will be used in the view. Can somebody tell me how can I use fields in this CMS?

Comment: Comfortable MExican Sofa? `CMS` do you mean?

Comment: I don't think I follow your question. What do you mean by 'CMS do you mean?' I have wrote `how can I use fields in this CMS?`

Comment: @Mahan I can see you got +1 upvote, so I guess I am missing the point. Could you explain me what did you mean with your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a CMS site set up so it's using an application layout. Somewhere in that layout you have: `<meta name="description" content="Something about the page">` Now, how do you dynamically populate content of that tag from the page? We can define `{{cms:field:meta_description}}` tag.

In the admin area you'll be able to populate it and. Now you need to output that like this:
`<meta name="description" content="<%= cms_block_content(:meta_description) %>">`

Comment: Yes, that is something that I have read that in the documentation, but what I was puzzled is - where I populate the `meta_description`. Where do I set the value for it?

Comment: It's a field that shows up when you're editing a cms page. CMS layout defines content areas, CMS page populates them. One of the areas is the {{ cms:field:meta_description }}

Comment: Hm, ok, you are probably right. I say probably as I have moved my application to another server and I can't test this very moment. but I believe you are right, I will mark it as answered. thanks for the effort

Comment: I'm very confused.  Where do I define this tag?  Is there a hidden tags section of the admin ui?  Is there a file somewhere where I define it?  What do I have to do in order to get a this field you are talking about to show up on the page edit screen?

Comment: @olleicua You define tags inside cms layout. See: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Tags

Comment: @Grocery I'm also confused, the wiki page only describes the general rules for tags, but it doesn't say where to actually DEFINE tag like :meta_description. There must be a place where something like this is defined using ie. '=' operator, for example {{cms:field:meta_description = 'lorem ipsum'}} (just w wild guess)

Comment: @januszm you define those inside CMS Layout. I usually cram them before any other cms tags. They don't get rendered out, but they are needed to render fields in admin area.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand and I will probably update CMS wiki. The cryptic part is that you have to write these tags/fields inside the layout and then they will appear as ... INPUT fields in the admin section, when editing the page